# Pull content from tablen into a class

Tags: c#, linq

I sit in a problem that do that it will not udhente some content from the database into my class,

it must be such that I have to download content from the database.

**error are**

> Provides for a specific object reference to the 'point.db' which is a field, a method or a property that is not static

i have try to this here

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();

public static string OpretBrugerPointAdd()
{
    PointBonus pointbonusStart = db.PointBonus.FirstOrDefault(P => P.Id == 1);
    if (pointbonusStart != null)
    {
        return Convert.ToString(pointbonusStart.point);
    }
}
```

when I call it happens like this,

```
string pointAntal = point.OpretBrugerPointAdd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use *non-static* field from *static* method. That's not going to work.

You should instantiate new `DataClassesDataContext` within your method instead:

```
public static string OpretBrugerPointAdd()
{
    using(var db = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        PointBonus pointbonusStart = db.PointBonus.FirstOrDefault(P => P.Id == 1);
        if (pointbonusStart != null)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(pointbonusStart.point);
        }
    }
}
```

You also have to deal with a fact, that your method doesn't return anything when `if` statement condition evaluates to `false`. You should probably add `return null` (or other *default* value you wish) at the very end of you mehtod to fix that.

Comment: error say 'point.OpretBrugerPointAdd()': not all code paths return a value.

Comment: hey, I do not see what you mean completely,

Comment: I see what you mean now. I hope you give me a +1 for questions as for you.